# How to use Amyuni PDF converter 4.0 in PowerBuilder 2017 without “run as Administrator”

Tags: powerbuilder, pdf-conversion

We have an application in PB 2017 that using Amyuni PDF Converter 4.0 to print the report in PDF file. The application works well until we upgrade the PC to Windows 10. There is a message "Printer not activated, error code -30" when printing the PDF. If we run the program "as administrator", it works. But there are some users who cannot run as administrator and so they cannot print the reports in PDF.

Any advice for this issue?

Comment: Try this: https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3021&p=9523&hilit=registry+permissions#p9523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by modifying the permissions of the printer in Registry.

1. Go to Registry and navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\*my_printer_name*.
2. Right-click the printer key and select Permissions from the menu.
3. Select Users and grant "Full Control" permissions for Users

Now the PDF file can be printed without running the program "as administrator"

Answer (score 1):

Amyuni Error code -30 mean that the licensed session expired.

The Amyuni PDF Converter must be enabled each time before output is sent to it. An application must call EnablePrinter() function passing the "License to" and "activation code" values immediately before a print job is sent to the Amyuni PDF Converter.

After EnablePrinter() is called, the application has about 20 seconds before the licensed session expires. If the printer does not receive a print job within 20 seconds the printing process will fail with "Printer not activated, error code -30".

Ps. You cannot print a test page to the Amyuni PDF Converter.

Here are explanations for the other error codes: [What do the Amyuni "Printer Not Activated" errors mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63909029/8534150)