# What do the Amyuni "Printer Not Activated" errors mean?

Tags: debugging, pdf-conversion

What does it mean when I get these errors from Amyuni PDF Converter (PDF Printer Driver)

"Printer Not Activated, error code -20"

"Printer Not Activated, error code -21"

"Printer Not Activated, error code -22"

"Printer Not Activated, error code -30"

"Printer Not Activated, error code -40"

"Printer Not Activated, error code -41"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Code -20: Name of licensee could not be read
Source: License registry entry not found

Error Code -21: Activation code could not be read
Source: (Code registry entry not found)

Error Code -22: Activation code does not correspond to Licensee
Source: wrong combination of Licensee/Code

Error Code -30: the PDF Printer was activated but timed out after about 20 seconds

Error Code -40: The activation code is not for the right Windows version (e.g. an activation code for XP 32-bits used under XP 64-bits)

Error Code -41: The activation code that is used is for a lower version number. (e.g. a 2.1 activation code used with version 2.5)

Source: https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1608&p=4899#p4910